# Subtleties of exec in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec

This stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC GetPage(@blockNumber int, @blockSize int = 40, @query varchar(1000)) 
AS
   DECLARE @a int = @blockNumber * @blockSize;
   DECLARE @b int = @a + @blockSize - 1;
   DECLARE @fromPos int = PATINDEX('% FROM %', @query);
   DECLARE @from varchar(1000) = SUBSTRING(@query, @fromPos, 1000);
   DECLARE @select varchar(1000) = SUBSTRING(@query, 1, @fromPos);
   DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000) = 
      'select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ONE) R INTO #FOO FROM ('
      +@SELECT+',1 ONE'+@from+') T';

   EXEC @SQL;

   SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE RN BETWEEN @a AND @b;

   DECLARE @C INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #FOO);
   DROP TABLE #FOO
   RETURN @C;
```

when passed `SELECT * FROM ASSET` generates this SQL

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ONE) R INTO #FOO 
FROM (select * ,1 ONE from asset) T
```

When I execute this from SQL Server Management Studio, like this:

```
exec('select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ONE) R INTO #FOO FROM (select * ,1 ONE from asset) T')
```

it creates the table #FOO as expected.

However, when the stored procedure is executed:

```
exec getpage 5,10,'select * from asset'
```

I get this error

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure GetPage, Line 12
>   Could not find stored procedure 'select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ONE) R INTO FOO FROM (select * ,1 ONE from asset) T'.
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetPage, Line 14
>   Invalid object name '#FOO'.

I think the second message is merely a consequence of the first error. Does anyone know why the `exec` statement is behaving differently inside a stored procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use parenthesis in your exec

```
EXEC (@SQL);
```

[EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Without the parenthesis you are using this:

```
Execute a stored procedure or function
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      [ @return_status = ]
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      [ ,...n ]
      [ WITH  [ ,...n ] ]
    }
[;]
```

You want this where the parenthesis is required.

```
Execute a character string
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
    [ AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name ' ]
[;]
```

Comment: As it happens I worked this out myself, but that just makes me certain you have offered a correct answer. Kudos are yours. Thank you for helping. You'd think they'd infer from the argument type as happens with .NET methods...

Comment: @mikael-eriksson - Is there anyway to use parentheses but assign the output of the proc to a variable something like @a = exec (@sql)